# Examples of fast .NET WPF/WinForms apps?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, winforms

I am currently investigating whether to build a windows application using unmanaged C/C++ or in .NET and would like to know of the kind of performance and responsiveness that is capable with a managed C#/.NET GUI app?

Not surprisingly it looks like the fastest most responsive applications (e.g. chrome, spotify, etc) are written in unmanaged C/C++. I've had a hard time finding examples of really good .NET applications and so I would like some help.

What's the best example of a fast and responsive .NET windows application?

Comment: Windows Forms apps are as fast as unmanaged ones. WPF apps are slow at redrawing when you resize their windows, but otherwise can be as fast as unmanaged.

Comment: @Cannibal: I disagree with both of your statements. 1. Many WPF applications are every bit as snappy as unmanaged applications at handling resizing. In general WPF applications handle redraw much faster than typical unmanaged techniques when animations are involved (WPF uses Direct3D which is too complex for most unmanaged). 2. WinForms has its slowdowns too, for example it tends to be slower than both unmanaged and WPF for many advanced graphics uses such as 3D, transparency, etc. 3. Unmanaged code may be the slowest of the three at times because it is so much more work to optimize it.

Comment: It might be better to look for benchmarks and techniques, than arbitrary apps that likely would have no relevance to the use case you're planning for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [latest version of](http://www.bing.com/maps/explore/) Bing Maps is written in silverlight which counts as managed code.

[Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) is written in some form of .net (although I think it ships it's own version of silverlight with it so it has no other dependencies).

A few years ago, most RSS readers were written in .net. I think that the responsiveness is going to be down to what you're programming rather than what you use. At the end of the day with multithreading you can make the app responsive while it's processing no matter what framework you use.

Comment: Looks like Bing maps has improved leaps and bounds - looks like the best example here.

Answer (score 7):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) is an Open Source example of an application written in .Net.

Answer (score 5):

[WorldWide Telescope](http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/Home.aspx) is a .NET graphics-intensive application that lets you browse a virtual night-sky as well as many other items releated to astronomy. It handles pretty massive amounts of data. Even though it seems to be in perpetual beta, it provides a very compelling user experience.

[Windows Live Writer](http://download.live.com/writer) is another .NET application. It may not be a very big application, but it excels at what it does, and I've never had any issues with its responsiveness.

Comment: I have to say that the WorldWide Telescope does look pretty implressive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of my favorites.

http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx

Once you install it, open the Windsor family and click around.  Be sure to try:

- The "Time" and "Zoom" sliders in the lower left and right corners of the window.
- Typing in the "Filter" box in the lower right

Family.Show has several intentional delays inserted for a more compelling user experience, for example animations are used when navigating around the family tree.  If you edit the source code and change the durations of all animations to "0" you will find that everything happens pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 2):

[Greenshot is an OSS .NET app](http://www.getgreenshot.org), which A LOT of people have set to start with windows (replaces SnagIt comercial app).  It is Windows Forms.  A quick check from process explorer confirms they use NGEN to reduce JIT time/overhead (Greenshot.ni.exe).

[GitHub for Windows is WPF](http://windows.github.com/) (IIUC mostly hand-coded XAML).  Of course all the git operations are pass-thru to native libgit2 library.

Most of Visual Studio UI is managed.  I'd say it is fast (fast enough for me) and gets faster with every release, despite moving more and more of the UI from C++/Win32/COM to C#/WPF/.NET . VS does play a lot of tricks to get this speed.  IL layout is optimized for usage patters after many profiling runs, post-build, and then after local install the IL is pre-jitted (NGEN), so most code that runs at startup is already native code from NGEN.

Answer (score 1):

**TOAD for MySQL** is a .NET application. It is pretty snappy. See http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/faq.htm

Also, the upcoming version of **Visual Studion 2010** has a lot of UI written in WPF. The performance of the Release Candidate looks good IMO.

Answer (score 0):

DigiTweet is written in WPF http://www.digitweet.com/